# I have trouble connecting js files using html

Tags: javascript, html

What I want do find out is how I can make this work so it makes a red box at location 100,100, using a function as my main function and another function to draw the image but I want it to be in a different js file.
2 js files and 1 html file.

[image: Code screenshot]

Code
    //HTML code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Prufa Einar</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id = "myCanvas" width="600" height = "600"
            style ="border: 1px solid black;">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src "draw.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src "main.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            main();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
//first js.file
var canvas;
var ctx;
var main = function()
{
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        draw(ctx);
};
//second js file
var draw = function(ctx)
{
    {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
        ctx.fillRect(100,100,20,20);
    }
};
```

Comment: Add the code to the question, not just a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need equal sign after src. 
src=""

and canvas out of head into body instead

Comment: little, but no problem ;) Glad it was it that simple.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question, this helps the poster of the answer @CreativeCreator , and others that may encounter the same problem.